set row timestamp value to actual time the row becomes available
I am working on my PostgreSQL, and I have encountered an issue when running large(ish, a few hundred to a few thousands rows with foreign keys) commits.
I recently learned that now() actually refers to the time at the beginning of a transaction, but I'd like to have my data stored with the timestamp of when they actually become available to be queried by other connections.
Below is an example, with sleeping time instead of inserts
drop table if exists test_table;
create temp table test_table (
id serial4 not null,
value int4 not null,
transaction_started_at timestamp default (now()) not null, 
insert_emitted_at timestamp not null,
constraint primary_key primary key (id)
);

begin;
insert into test_table (value, insert_emitted_at) values (1, clock_timestamp());
select pg_sleep(5); -- imagine a lot of inserts there
insert into test_table (value, insert_emitted_at) values (2, clock_timestamp());
commit;

select *, clock_timestamp() as appears_in_database_at from test_table
-- since executed immedialty after, the clock_timestamp() in select is close enough to the actual end of the commit

(Note that in my real life example, the insertion commands do not take that long, it's really the commit that takes long)
I get the following result
id|value|transaction_started_at |insert_emitted_at      |appears_in_database_at       |
--+-----+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+
 1|    1|2024-11-07 15:05:34.506|2024-11-07 15:05:34.529|2024-11-07 15:05:39.737 +0100|
 2|    2|2024-11-07 15:05:34.506|2024-11-07 15:05:39.687|2024-11-07 15:05:39.737 +0100|

So there is a significant time difference between what I would get by setting now() as my default column value and the actual time the row becomes available in the database !
This means that an external service querying the table would not get consistent results depending on when it runs the query.
For example, the request SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE value = 2 AND insert_emitted_at < '2024-11-07 15:05:39.700' would return:

Nothing before 2024-11-07 15:05:39.687 (duh, the insert was not emitted)
Nothing between 2024-11-07 15:05:39.687 and 2024-11-07 15:05:39.739
Only afterwards will we have one result.

This can be a big issue for me as I am using such column for jobs which basically do "Select columns that have been inserted in the past X minutes and do an operation on them." (In this specific example I'd have to be really unlucky, but on a real life example the INSRTS
Is there a way to get in a column the actual time it becomes available in the database outside of the transaction ? Or is PostgreSQL not meant to be used for time-sensitive work such as this ?
If demonstrated that having such  timestamp is not possible, I'd be willing to accept an answer with your transactions should be shorter but this is the worst case scenario for me :'(

See/use clock_timestamp.

Interesting! Rows become 'available' when the transaction commits, which is 5231 ms after beginning of the transaction, of which 5000 are the "simulated" inserts (sleep). If that is too much, what would be acceptable? Also, getting the commit time of a transaction from inside the transaction is "logically impossible". Can you please also define "time-sensitive"? Have you considered batch inserts for high throughput, or is throughput no topic?

Yes it is called autocommit, then each insert will be committed immediately and will be seen at that time. The downside is that is  lot of transactions and the time for all the inserts will increase dramatically. Though I don't see a problem with  the current setup. Until the commit happens the concurrent sessions won't them anyway and from their POV they will be new rows.

@hobgoblin Note that in real life, the commit part could also take much more time. Ideally, the delay would be "small enough so there is virtually no difference for an external service".
Use case example:  another service runs "query the rows ingested in test_table between now() and 2 minutes ago (based on either column), check the value and if it meets certain criteria, notify an user". If my insert takes 5 minutes, then no rows will ever be checked...
I have considered batch inserting, but my real life use-case also has foreign keys shenanigans which make it harder.

I appears to me that you have two problems: short latency of individual inserts (or grops of them), and finding the commit time. Which is the main problem? For latency of an insert, you could also set "read uncommitted" transaction isolation level, but you will loose some consistency.

@AdrianKlaver yes, this is the direction I am probably going to follow, though not ideal because it will indeed make the inserts much longer...

@hobgoblin I see your point, I think I can reformulate the issue like "I cannot pinpoint -with a low enough latency - when a row will be returned by a query ran by an external service". Then the two alternatives you present are just two ways to solve the problem :)
I'll edit my question to clarify thanks to your comments !
Reading uncommited would also be a solution, but if the transaction rolls back, I would not be able to find the row

FYI, in Postgres  READ UNCOMMITED maps to READ COMMITTED per Transaction Isolation, so that is not an option.

At the moment, my current solution is:

reduce the transaction duration (within the capabilities of my real life example)
Give a larger buffer for my external jobs, e.g my job that runs every 2 minutes which does "query the rows ingested in test_table between now() and x minutes ago (based on either column), check the value and if it meets certain criteria, notify an user" will check for 3 minutes and not just 2 minutes :)


Or create a jobs table that records the now()/CURRENT_TIMESTAMP for a given job as well as set an active boolean field to 't' and then use  transaction_started_at as your search filter. Set active field to 'f' when the select query is done.

@AdrianKlaver Thanks, you are correct about read uncommitted = read committed, I forgot that, but your link goes to sql_copy. Sadly, I cannot edit it, but here is pg-17 tx-isolation.

Oops sorry grabbed wrong link out of clipboard.
